# Wait for other transaction to commit/rollback before beginning another transaction?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-4.0, transactions, mysql-connector

How can I make my transactions to wait if there is still an un-committed/un-roll-backed transaction in MySQL?

Currently I do my transactions on the code side, not on the DB Stored Procedure side, like this:

```
cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();
try {
    // db codes here
    cmd.Transaction.Commit();
} catch {
    cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
    throw;
} finally {
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

I want for other transactions to wait until the previous transaction is finished. Since I have, in some of my stored proc, that gets the `MAX(id)` when inserting for a foreign keys, where `id` is an auto-incremented column that is also created on the same transaction. But it doesn't work on my current setup above when 2 transactions occur at the same time, what happened is like this:

```
Begin Trans1
Begin Trans2
Trans1: insert a values(); --id = 1
Trans2: insert a values(); --id = 1
Trans1: insert b(aid, col1) values((select MAX(id) from a), 'test'); --aid = 1
Trans2: insert b(aid, col1) values((select MAX(id) from a), 'test'); --aid = 1
Commit Trans1
Commit Trans2 --id = 2, aid = 1
```

What I was hoping is like this:

```
Begin Trans1
Wait Trans2
Trans1: insert a values(); --id = 1
Trans1: insert b(aid, col1) values((select MAX(id) from a), 'test'); --aid = 1
Commit Trans1
Begin Trans2
Trans2: insert a values(); --id = 2
Trans2: insert b(aid, col1) values((select MAX(id) from a), 'test'); --aid = 2
Commit Trans2
```

Is it possible like this?

Comment: i have edited my post check if it helps in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using **IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted** you can avoid the access to the table involved in a transaction by other transaction

```
cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
```

or

you can use TransactionScope class.
TransactionScope makes the Code block transactional,till the code is  not committed the tables will be locked and if some other requests the same table then it will have to wait until the running transaction is committed or rolled back.

[refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks. I was actually already looking at the `IsolationLevel` but I can't understand the MSDN article. XD

Comment: I use `IsolationLevel.Serializable` instead to make sure that read is also locked. Would other transactions will wait until the tables is unlocked, or it will just throw an exception?