# How to wait for a SQL Server database rollback to complete?

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactions

When using the ADO.NET `SqlClient` classes, there are a few ways in which a transaction can be rolled back. Either by explicitly calling `SqlTransaction.Rollback`, or having a command timeout, or a transaction timeout within a transaction scope etc.

But how can I detect when this rollback has completed when using SQL Server (2012 or later)? For a long running transaction the rollback may take a long time, and it is usually quite IO-intensive on the database, so it may not be wise to retry the transaction immediately. In our situation we would like to wait for the rollback to complete.

(In our specific case the rollback occurs because of a transaction timeout using the TransactionScope class, but I would prefer a method that would work for any kind of rollback).

I have looked at the `sys.dm_exec_requests` which looked promising at first. It had a command type of `KILL/ROLLBACK` at first, and reported the progress percentage. (If I captured the SPID from the original transaction I would be able to poll this table and wait for it to complete). However, about halfway through I noticed it changed to `AWAITING COMMAND` instead (while the rollback was still being performed).

I also looked at `KILL <SPID> WITH STATUSONLY`. This seems to generate an error if there is no rollback in progress, so it could work as well for a polling approach, but I noticed that if I ran a `BEGIN TRAN ... ROLLBACK TRAN` batch from SSMS, this reported an error saying that no rollback was in progress when it was rolling back. The `dm_exec_requests` table reported `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` as the command type in this case.

So how can I wait for a rollback to complete in a reliable way?

Comment: Because the load on the SQL server is too high during the rollback to even attempt to re-run the transaction in this case. So we want to wait until the rollback is complete and the database server has more resources available for performing the next actual transaction.

Comment: Sorry I removed my comment because I find an answer in my question. I was asking of "Why bother if you're in READ_COMMITED your code shall not read data uncommited?" Also in .NET, your request will wait for completion of your transaction in this option.

Comment: Similar question, though worded differently. It seems you want to wait until a current transaction is committed or rolled back before attempting another one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457955/wait-for-other-transaction-to-commit-rollback-before-beginning-another-transacti

Comment: @WilliamXifaras This question mostly deals with locking between transactions it seems. If my transaction is aborted for whatever reason, eg. `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` throws an exception after 10 min because of a transaction timeout, I want to wait for the database to complete the rollback.

Comment: If its a timing / performance issue, perhaps you should break out your work into smaller units. Also sys.dm_exec_requests seems to be your best bet in terms of querying for status.

Answer (score 0):

You can see transaction activity with `sp_who` based on `spid`. The column `status` will tell you the current state of transaction and change from `rollback` or disapear when finished.

If you want to have a feedback on .NET, use [SqlChangeMonitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.sqlchangemonitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)([example](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/167282/net-4-0-memorycache-with-sqlchangemonitor.aspx)) to cache your result and wait for your `SqlChangeMonitor` to notify a change from `rollback`.

---

In case you fix your problem of timeout you can look to:

Using **IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted**. That way your .NET code will wait for completion of your Commit or Rollback.

(It will look like `cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)` with `cmd` of type `SqlCommand` )

Comment: I don't believe it will. If a transaction timeout occurs, (in a TransactionScope for example), an exception saying "Transaction Aborted" is thrown, and the execution of the .NET code continues as usual, while the SQL Server can spend a long time running the rollback. Not sure why the isolation level would change this?

Comment: In the first place your request shall not timeout. If it does it could mean 2 things. Your request is poorly designed (usually due to high complexity without proper segmentation) OR you didn't set a correct `CommandTimeout` (set at 30sec by default).

In the second case, using previous example, you can just do something like `cmd.CommandTimeout = 180` (set to 3 minutes)

Comment: Yes, it would be desireable for the request not to timeout. But the question deals with the circumstance where it *does*, and a rollback is initiated implicitly.

Comment: Edited to match your question. But I still think that having timeout is something to avoid at any cost. It will add hardly maintainable/readable code to your project at best. At worst, it will add unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlRollback.cs 

using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;

namespace Events
{
    public class SqlRollback
    {
        private string _connString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=QueryIt.EmployeeDb;Trusted_Connection=true";
        public event EventHandler TransactionRolledBack;

        public void Transact()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var command = conn.CreateCommand();
                SqlTransaction transaction;
                transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("Transaction");

                command.Connection = conn;
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                try
                {
                    transaction.Save("checkpoint");
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees (name, discriminator) VALUES ('Dimitar', 'Bastun')";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    throw new Exception();

                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback("checkpoint"); //Rolling back to the checkpoint
                    Thread.Sleep(5000); //Simulating some time
                    transaction.Commit();
                    this.OnTransactionRollingBack(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnTransactionRollingBack(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = TransactionRolledBack;
            if(handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}

Program.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Events
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rollBack = new SqlRollback();
            rollBack.TransactionRolledBack += RollBack_TransactionRolledBack;

            try
            {
                rollBack.Transact();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        private static void RollBack_TransactionRolledBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Rooled!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in reality though the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` would throw an exception upon timeout causing the rollback to commence before we have a chance to call `transaction.Rollback`, after which we can probably neither rollback or commit the transaction.